# Creating Algorithm: Box Split when there is maximum no.of points in the box

Tags: c, algorithm

Hello I need help with making algorithm with the following:

Let's say a 2d domain of space with xmax, xmin, ymin, ymax, with 'n~10,000' of points in the space.

1. Go through lists of points positions.
2. When there is maximum no,of points (lets say 10) in the box, the box split into 4 equal smaller boxes.
3. Then check again if the each of the smaller box has more than maximum no. of points. it will split again into 4 equal smaller boxes.... until the box has less than the maximum no.of points per box.

Any suggestions how I can make this algorithm? Please?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to program this yourself and then **ask again** as soon as you run into problems.

To get you started here's an idea: create **two arrays of indices** that just go up from 0 to the number of points you have. Then use the x-values of the points to sort one index-array and the y-values to sort the other index-array. You can then read what you need by simply taking the **n-th** entry from each array and combine the x/y-maxima of the 2 points you got. (Also: To then get the next cross-point you dont need to sort again, just use the next n'th entries)